# Query fails when file doesnt exist

Tags: file, csv, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I am trying to load a set of files, containing information regarding multiple clusters, that share a similar location and name. Unfortunately, for some of these clusters the file hasnt been created yet.

What I tried to do was to hardcode the names of the files I know do not exist yet but I would like to do this in a way that I would skip those files instead of hardcoding every single time a file hasn't been created yet.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM apoc.text.join(['file:///my/cluster/', cluster, '/databases.csv'], '') as line
```

I would like to know if there's a way of doing this using Cypher. If not, then my fix will be to create each respective folder and then an empty file inside.

Comment: What do you mean by "skip those files"? Do you mean that the query is written in such a way that it can still do useful things even when the file is empty? If so, then I think your workaround is the easiest solution.

Comment: Hy cybersam,

By skipping the files, I mean that the query wont brake if the file is not present and will continue processing the other files. I already implemented my workaround because I haven't found anything that would allow this and it was easier and faster to do it like this but if there is, Im interested in knowing how to do it.